# HTML tag or CSS Text Format Text Same Height

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve this text format.

```
<p>you 10 oz bottle</p>
```

[image]

The text number "10" and text "oz" has same height. Is there anyway to achieve this? Or do I need some fonts to achieve this text format? Can someone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add your current code segment

Comment: What are you trying to do? Have "10 OZ" share the same font-size? Or are you trying to supertext the "oz" (e.g: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup)?

Comment: More information would be helpful. Are you trying to transform lowercase letters to uppercase? What have you tried and what seems to be preventing you from achieving your goal?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Hello sir thanks for replying. Yes sir I want it to be of the same height both of the "10" and "oz" inside a paragraph tag.  I don't want it to be superscripted.

Comment: @hungerstar I have edited my question sir. Inside in a paragraph.

Comment: @kushan I have edited my question sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your the number in another element you can target to adjust the font-size accordingly. Or simply wrap it in `small` tags.

`<span>You have <small>10</small> oz bottle</span>`

```html
<span>You have a <small>10</small> oz bottle</span>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Sorry I'm just learning this.

Comment: I'm curious how this is the accepted answer. The numbers and letters are not the same size as requested in the original post. It would be a complete answer if the code snippet actually produced the equal sized numbers and text.

Comment: I believe it's simply because the text remains lowercase. And although they are not precisely equal in font-size, it wouldn't be difficult to just slap on a custom rule to the `small` element to make the necessary adjustments required to set them at equal sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot to go on. But I'll try.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.size {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p>
    I have a <span class="size">10 <span class="unit">oz</span></span> bottle.
</p>
```

Notice the source text is lowercase. After the CSS is applied it is uppercase.

Though I am a bit wary that this might not work for all fonts, numbers, letters etc. The baseline positioning and heights of some characters may not work out as well as it does with **Arial**. That is why I wrapped **oz** in a `<span>` so it could be individually targeted if the font size needs adjustment.

Comment: Thanks you sir for answering. I will try this first.

Comment: Hello sir. I have edited my question. This is what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: @hungerstar  - sorry to hear you're a bit weary - I would personally be very wary about being weary - it tends to make you tired --- just joking... ;-)

Comment: @TonyDuffill doh!